# Adding a fresh GUID per record via SQL syntax?

Tags: sql

I'm working with multiple existing tables in a couple databases that didn't previously have a uniqueidentifier column. I have since added this column, but I'm wondering if there's a SQL method I can use to assign each column their own GUID. I work with VB.Net and I know I can do it there but considering the size and number of the tables that could take a great deal of time to cycle through.

I've got this, which will assign the same GUID to each row, but I'm wondering if there's a clean way to reset the GUID per-record within the SQL syntax?

```
    DECLARE @NewGUID uniqueidentifier
    SET @NewGUID = NEWID()
    UPDATE tblSample
    SET [GUID] = @NewGUID
    WHERE GUID IS NULL
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign NEWID() directly to the column, instead of storing one value in a variable:

```
UPDATE tblSample SET [GUID] = NEWID() WHERE GUID IS NULL
```